# HTML / CSS - margin in flexbox

Tags: html

I'm having a margin issue.
Could someone explain to me where does the margin on this picture comes from ? I can't see where I would have set it in my code. When flex set on row, there still is a top margin but no margin in left.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Shq.png)

I need to set margin on this element and I don't understand why I need to do that. Why is there this margin at the top of the container?

```
.form > div{ 
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Thanks

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
}

.container { /* règles générale de mise en forme des containers */
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 100%;
  
}



h3{ /*  */
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}



/*---------------------MENU------------------------------- */


.menu > div.container { /* couleur fond menu */
    background-color: #DD5555; 
}


.ElementsMenu { /* pour organiser le menu horizontalement avec espacements */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* éléments vont à la ligne si largeur de page trop petite */
    margin-left: 100px;
    gap: 2rem;
  }

  .ElementsMenu > li { /* selectionne tous les éléments du menu */
    display: flex; 
    height: 52px; /* hauteur du menu */
    justify-content: center; /* centrer horizontalement */
    align-items: center; /* centrer verticalement */
    list-style: none; /* supprime les puces */
} 



a{ /* Mise en forme de la police du menu */
    text-decoration : none; /* supprimer soulignage du texte menu */
    color: #FFFFFF;
}



/*---------------------FIN MENU------------------------------- */









/*---------------------INTRO------------------------------- */



h1{ /* titre SUPER APP */
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: #FFFFFF;
   /* border: 1px solid white; */
}

h2{ /* sous-titre  */
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 5px;
   /* border: 1px solid white; */
}

.intro > div.container{
    background-image: url("images/about.jpg.png"); /* image de fond */
    background-size: cover; /* pour que l'image prenne tout l'espace */
    height:848px; /* hauteur du conteneur */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10 px;
    align-items: center;  /* alignement horizontal */
    padding-top: 280px; /* alignement vertical */
}


hr{
    width:480px;
    margin-top:20px;
} 

div.icones{
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    gap: 4.5rem;
}


figure.icone{
    width  : 112px;
    height : 46px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #FFFFFF ;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.icone > img{
   margin-left: 13px;
}

figcaption {
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }


/*---------------------FIN INTRO------------------------------- */






/*---------------------SERVICES------------------------------- */

.services{ /* titre et description en colonne */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 848px;
    padding-left:131px;
    padding-right:131px;
}

.services h3{ /* titre ELLE FAIT DES TRUCS SUPERS ! */
    margin-top: 52px;
}

.services .logo{ /* ronds rouges fond logos */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #DD5555;

    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center; /* centrer horizontalement */
    align-items: center; /* centrer verticalement */

   /* border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); */
}


h4{ /* titres des services */
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.txtServ{ /* texte descriptif des services */
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}





.ligne1{ /* les trois 1er services disposés en ligne */
    display:flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content:center;
    gap:2rem;
    margin-top:4rem;
    /* border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); */

}



.ligne2{ /* les trois derniers services disposés en ligne */
    display:flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content:center;
    gap:2rem;
    margin-top:4rem;
    /* border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); */

}

.service1, .service2, .service3, .service4, .service5, .service6{ /* mise en forme de chaque élément service */
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; /* centrer horizontalement */
    align-items: center; /* centrer verticalement */
    gap: 1.5rem;
   /* border: 1px solid rgb(83, 65, 201); */
    
}



/*---------------------FIN SERVICES------------------------------- */






.team{ /* disposition titre et contenu en colonne */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}

.team > h1{ /* mise en forme titre */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:240px;
    background-image: url('images/team.jpg.png');
    background-size: cover;
    /* border: 1px solid rgb(83, 65, 201); */
}

.membres{ /*disposition membres en ligne */
    height: 494px;
    display:flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content:space-between;
    gap:4rem;
    margin-top:4rem;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

.membres .avatar{
    height: 239px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.membres > div{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap:2rem;
}

.mail{
    width: 132px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    background-color: #DD5555;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap:0.5rem;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.membres p{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}






.contact{ /*taille et fonc de section */
    height: 476px;
    background-color: #DD5555;
    border: 1px solid rgb(83, 65, 201);
}


.contact > .container{ /* titre et contenu disposés verticalement */
    /* border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);*/
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap:2rem;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
 }

.contact h3{ /* titre */
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 52px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}



.form{ /* lignes du form en colonnes */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap:1rem;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.form > div{ /* éléments de chaque lignes disposés en ligne */
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.ligne1 > div{ /* intitulés et cases de ligne1 en colonne */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.ligne1 .case{ /* mise en forme cases nom et mail*/
   width: 358px; 
   height: 32px;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   border-radius: 2%;
}


.mess .case{ /* mise en forme case mess*/
    width: 748px;
    height: 112px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 2%;
    margin-top: 4px;
}


.contact p{ /* mise en forme intitulés */
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}


/*

.ligne2{
}


.ligne3{
    /*width: 123px;
    height: 46px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
   /* border: 1px solid rgb(83, 65, 201);
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SuperApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="container">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="ElementsMenu">
                        <li class="logo"><img src="images/Logo.png"  alt="Logo"></li>
                        <li><a href="">&Agrave propos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">L'équipe</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <section class="intro">
            <div class="container">
                    <h1> SUPER APP !</h1>
                    <h2> L'application trop super !</h2>
                    <hr></hr>
                    <div class="icones">
                        <figure class="icone"> 
                            <img src="images/thumbs-up.svg" alt="Like it"> 
                            <figcaption>Like it</figcaption> </figure>
                        <figure class="icone"> 
                            <img src="images/heart-shape-silhouette.svg" alt="Love it"> 
                            <figcaption>Love it</figcaption> </figure>
                        <figure class="icone"> 
                            <img src="images/shopping-cart-black-shape.svg" alt="Buy it"> 
                            <figcaption>Buy it</figcaption> 
                        </figure>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="services">
            <h3>ELLE FAIT DES TRUCS SUPERS !</h3>
            <div class="ligne1">
                <div class="service1">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="images/fork-and-knife-silhouette.svg"></div>
                    <h4>Mettre la table</h4>
                    <p class="txtServ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci reiciendis voluptate beatae nihil.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="service2">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="images/bed.svg"></div>
                    <h4>Faire le lit</h4>
                    <p class="txtServ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci reiciendis voluptate beatae nihil.</p>

                </div>
                <div class="service3">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="images/fire-symbol.svg"></div>
                    <h4>Allumer le feu</h4>
                    <p class="txtServ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci reiciendis voluptate beatae nihil.</p>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ligne2">
                <div class="service4">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="images/plant-leaf-with-white-details.svg"></div>
                    <h4>Ramasser les feuilles</h4>
                    <p class="txtServ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci reiciendis voluptate beatae nihil.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="service5">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="images/umbrella-black-silhouette.svg"></div>
                    <h4>Protéger de la pluie</h4>
                    <p class="txtServ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci reiciendis voluptate beatae nihil.</p>

                </div>
                <div class="service6">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="images/dollar-symbol.svg"></div>
                    <h4>Vider votre compte</h4>
                    <p class="txtServ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci reiciendis voluptate beatae nihil.</p>

                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="team">
            <h1>La super équipe à l'origine de SuperApp</h1>
            <div class="membres">
                <div class="m1">
                    <img class="avatar" src="images/avaone.jpg.png" alt="membre1">
                    <h4>Tex Talign</h4>
                    <div class="mail">
                        <img src="images/envelope.svg" alt="envelope">
                        <p>Lui écrire</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="m2">
                    <img class="avatar" src="images/avatwo.jpg.png" alt="membre2">
                    <h4>Marge Inn</h4>
                    <div class="mail">
                        <img src="images/envelope.svg" alt="envelope">
                        <p>Lui écrire</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="m3">
                    <img class="avatar" src="images/avathree.jpg.png" alt="membre3">
                    <h4>Isaac Newton</h4>
                    <div class="mail">
                        <img src="images/envelope.svg" alt="envelope">
                        <p>Lui écrire</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="m4">
                    <img class="avatar" src="images/avafour.jpg.png" alt="membre4">
                    <h4>Ash Tehemel</h4>
                    <div class="mail">
                        <img src="images/envelope.svg" alt="envelope">
                        <p>Lui écrire</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="contact">
            <div class="container">
                <h3>ENVOYEZ-NOUS UN MESSAGE</h3>
                <div class="form">

                    <div class="ligne1">
                        <div class="nom">
                            <p>Votre nom</p>
                            <div class="case"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="email">
                            <p>Votre e-mail</p>
                            <div class="case"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ligne2">
                        <div class="mess">
                            <p>Votre message</p>
                            <div class="case"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ligne3">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </section>


    </main>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.ligne1{ /* les trois 1er services disposés en ligne */
    display:flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content:center;
    gap:2rem;
    margin-top:4rem; /* <<<< HERE IS YOUR MARGIN */
    /* border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); */
}
```

You can easily find this information by [inspecting the DOM](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/dom/#inspect) with your browser's developer tools.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the gap comes from:

```
.contact > .container {
    /* border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2rem;
}
```

remove gap:2rem; and the gap goes away